# SSIS 2008 R2 Setting Run64BitRuntime Value Through Script Task

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, bids

I have an SSIS project with multiple packages. I would like to create a "Master" package which would run the individual packages in a sequence. The first package contains a Data Flow task which imports data from Excel files, so my Run64BitRuntime setting is set to "false". The following package that needs to be run contains a Fuzzy Lookup, which requires that the Run64BitRuntime setting is set to "true".

Is there a way that I can change this project property setting through a Script Task, so that I can fully automate this process?

Comment: When your master runs, you'll need to run the alternate as a separate process via the Execute Process Task to use the right version of DTEXEC when it runs

Comment: I think that you will be able to do that in the SQL Server agent too. I mean you can move your login by with sequanced runtime in Agent by adding multiple steps into your job. Split your operation into two different package and change this property just in the Agent. The problem will be with debugging, but propably there is no easy option to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You Deploy the Packages in an SSIS Catalog (may be in your same instance of SQL).
In the SSISDB Database, we have several SPs. Some of them are listed below.

```
[SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
[SSISDB].catalog.start_execution
[SSISDB].catalog.create_execution
```

Every sp has its own purpose. see here
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878034.aspx

See syntax of

```
create_execution [ @folder_name = folder_name
     , [ @project_name = ] project_name
     , [ @package_name = ] package_name
  [  , [ @reference_id = ] reference_id ]
  [  , [ @use32bitruntime = ] use32bitruntime ]
     , [ @execution_id = ] execution_id OUTPUT
```

The parameter `@use32bitruntime` will help you to make changes in 32/64 bit execution.
With the above set of SPs you can have great control over package execution.

Comment: Is there something like SSIS Catalog for 2008 R2?